# Vim: strange escaping to normal mode behaviour

Tags: vim, character

When I'm escaping from insert mode with either `<esc>` or `jj` the cursor moves one character backwards, which, I guess, is the typical behavior for Vim or MacVim GUI.

I tried solving the problem by using `inoremap jj <esc>l` but the problem there is that when I'm at the end of the line the cursor jumps to the next line, which is even stranger.

I know I can go around this issue by getting used to `a` instead of `i` to jump back to insert mode, but first I want to be sure there is no other workaround.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry because this is not what you would be expecting, but you probably should get used to it instead of remapping it. In Vim, in normal mode, your cursor is not *between* characters but *on* characters. Traditional editors do not have a normal mode, you are always inserting and thus you need to see a cursor *between* characters.

If you still really want to do that, set `virtualedit` to `onemore`.

Comment: Or remove `l` from `whichwrap`. It's not a default.

Answer (score 0):

just simply `inoremap jj <esc>`